# Magento connect all options disabled

Tags: php, magento

Im running a new magento 1.9.1 but there are issues with the connect manager. All options are disabled. Leaving the page gives a javascript warning 'There are connect processes running'
I have tracked this down to an ajax call to to /downloader/index.php?A=empty which sais 'Please wait, preparing for updates...' in the green terminal style.

Also the iframe with the terminal does not show. Ive tried multiple browsers

Any idea what I have done wrong or how to correct this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to change the backend from hhvm 3.1, to php-fpm.